# VBA Move specific rows to unique new workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably really easy for someone with better knowledge of VBA than me. I can see how to do this if it's a case of copying rows into a new worksheet but haven't figured out how to get it to move to the next row once it has copied the first one that meets the condition.  I know I need to tell it to look for the next row but I'm having trouble finding the right command.

I'm looking to get the macro to cycle through my named range of data and copy one row that meets the condition at a time to a new unique workbook. For example, I have 10 records that meet the criteria, I want an output of 10 workbooks with one row of data in each.

Code so far is:

```
Sub DPD()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Items As Range
Dim Item As Range

Set Ws = Worksheets("Out")
Set Items = Ws.Range("MyRange")

For Each Item In Items

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'If value in column C > 0, copy row to new workbook and save
If Item.Value > 0 Then

    'Select row in active Sheet to copy
    Item.EntireRow.Copy

    'Paste row into new spreadsheet
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "C:\DPD"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\DPD\pf_" & Format(CStr(Now), "yyy_mm_dd_hh_mm") & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWindow.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


End If

Next Item
```

Link to Example [sheet](https://gofile.io/?c=8jA3HM)

Comment: The problem may be in your naming `...Format(CStr(Now), "yyy_mm_dd_hh_mm")...` - you will get new file name only once per minute, but macro runs much faster, so each your file with unique rows is simply overwritten. Try adding some counter: `dim counter as long`, then update loop with `...Format(CStr(Now), "yyy_mm_dd_hh_mm") & counter...` and `counter = counter +1` for each iteration.

Comment: Change your `For Each Item In Items` to `For Each Item In Items.Rows`. Then to reference your cell (i.e.: `If Item.Cells(1,1).Value > 0 Then`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my suggestion, try the below UDF

```
Sub DPD()

    ' Variable Declarations
    Dim rItem As Range
    Dim oNewWB As Workbook
    Dim oNewWS As Worksheet
    Dim iCounter As Long: iCounter = 0

    ' Switch updates off
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' Loop through all rows in the range
    For Each rItem In Range("MyRange").Rows

        ' Check if column C has a value greater than 0. NOTE: if the cell has text in it (i.e. header column will have text)
        '                                                     excel counts the number of characters in the cell.. which will
        '                                                     be greater than 0 so that line will be copied in a new workbook
        If rItem.Cells(1, 3).Value > 0 Then

            ' Create new workbook and get the first sheet
            Set oNewWB = Workbooks.Add
            Set oNewWS = oNewWB.Sheets(1)

            ' Copy current row
            rItem.Cells(1, 1).EntireRow.Copy

            ' Paste row in new worksheet
            oNewWS.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

            ' Save new workbook and close it
            iCounter = iCounter + 1
            oNewWB.SaveAs Filename:="C:\DPD\pf_" & Format(CStr(Now), "yyy_mm_dd_hh_mm") & counter & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
            oNewWB.Close

        End If
    Next

    ' Turn on updates
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tested this out and it generates only two workbooks for the 10 rows. The workbooks are also blank.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sheet?

Comment: I've uploaded a copy with the data replaced with dummy details here:  https://gofile.io/?c=8jA3HM

Comment: I'll have a look at it tonight

Comment: I noticed a mistake in the VBA which I've changed, it's generating the files now but not stopping when it reaches the last row with data, unfortunately it continues to generate 100 files which is the number of rows in my named range.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get a chance last night but will have a look tonight

Comment: No worries, I have it working now. The issue was with  If rItem.Cells(1, 3).Value > 0. The offset needed to be Cells(1,1) as otherwise it was looking at my vlookups in the other columns

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned in comment, the problem is in your naming. Here is refactored code for you. Check it, because I removed some stuff and moved other one.

```
Sub DPD()

Dim Items As range
Dim Item As range

'Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim newWS As Worksheet
Dim counter As Long

'Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet_name") ' try avoiding ActiveWorkbook/Sheet
'Set Items = WS.range("MyRange") ' - this is not necessary if you already have a named range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' thats right to switch off notifications
Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' but another good idea is to switch off screen update - this will allow vba to work much faster and you won't see blinking display

For Each Item In Range("MyRange") ' here's where you may use your named range directly

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------
' As per @Zac's comment:    
'For Each Item In Items.Rows ' should change the For loop condition
'If Item.Cells(1, 1).Value > 0 Then ' and also update an If statement
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------


'If value in column C > 0, copy row to new workbook and save
    If Item.Value > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Add
        Set newWS = ActiveSheet ' Here is the place where I can't avoid using "ActiveSheet"
        'Select row in active Sheet to copy
        Item.EntireRow.Copy

 'ChDir "C:\DPD" ' no need to change default directory, as you are providing full file name below ↓

        'Paste row into new spreadsheet
        With newWS
            .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            .Parent.SaveAs FileName:="C:\DPD\pf_" & Format(CStr(Now), "yyy_mm_dd_hh_mm") & counter & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
            .Parent.Close
        End With
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Next Item

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**Update**

As per Zac's comment - there truly may be more than one column in range, so I've added his suggestion to my answer.

Comment: Not sure this will work. Problem you have is that if the range has more than 1 column, you will then copy the same row as many times as there are number of columns in a new workbook everytime. So if there are 2 columns and 3 rows in the range, you will then copy row1 twice in 2 different workbooks.. and so on. See my comments to fix the problem

Comment: @Zac I understand that, by I look at OP's code, there you may find a comment `'If value in column C > 0,... ` , so I was assuming, that the range is set to only one column. But nevertheless, I will update my answer with your point as soon as I get to my PC :)

Comment: Thanks both, I'll test out your suggestions and see what happens :)

Comment: Ok so I have given this a test. I think the issue is as mentioned above it's not copying the following rows.  I have around 10 rows, it can change to a number of rows anywhere between 1-100.  Column C contains a numeric value which will always be populated if the row contains data in the other columns, which is why I used the 'If Item.Value > 0 Then'. The above works to copy the first row but when it loops back around it's not selecting the second row down, it copies the first again into a new workbook.

Comment: The above doesn't work for me. Loops through hundreds of times until I end it and creates the same one row record again and again.

Answer (score 0):

Your code basically works, the only problem is the files are created so fast that they are all created in the same second and

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\DPD\pf_" & Format(CStr(Now), "yyy_mm_dd_hh_mm") & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

will not allow you to distinguish the files. So all your files will have the same time stamp and are overwritten. A simple solution is to add a counter

```
iCounter
```

that increments with every new file, like in this edited piece of code:

```
Sub DPD()

Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim Items As Range
Dim Item As Range
Dim iCounter As Integer

Set Ws = Worksheets("Out")
Set Items = Ws.Range("MyRange")

For Each Item In Items

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'If value in column C > 0, copy row to new workbook and save
If Item.Value > 0 Then

    'Select row in active Sheet to copy
    Item.EntireRow.Copy

    'Paste row into new spreadsheet
    Workbooks.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ChDir "C:\DPD"

    iCounter = iCounter + 1
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\DPD\pf_" & Format(CStr(Now), "yyy_mm_dd_hh_mm") & iCounter & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV
    ActiveWindow.Close




End If

Next Item

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Please observe that I also moved the

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

out of the loop. Otherwise, screen updating will be turned on right after the first copy/paste.